# Why does Hotspot get disabled on Galaxy S23+ when I receive a call?

Tags: samsung, wifi-hotspot, voice-over-lte

I recently upgraded (?) from a Galaxy S8 to an S23+.
On the S8, I could use the hotspot and receive a call at the same time, without any interruption. However, if I receive a call on the S23+, it instantly kills the hotspot so I can no longer use my computer when on the call. Very frustrating.

I tried asking the EE shop to resolve the problem, plus technical support twice. No one had heard of this problem, they say!
I Googled the problem and learnt about VoLTE, which I understand prevented this problem on the S8 so that 3G calls used the 4G connection and did not kill my hotspot. Clearly, this does not do the same thing on the S23+.

I have tried doing 'network resets' and that doesn't work.
I have tried only allowing 4G (in Settings/Mobile Networks) in the hope that VoLTE will work that way. It doesn't!

Surely someone else out there has encountered this problem, and hopefully, has a solution?
Please help! Thanks

Comment: VoLTE should not affect the Wifi hotspot, but VoWifi may do so.

Comment: Agreed! VoLTE as I understand it should stop the problems I'm experiencing and not kill the hotspot! I don't ever use Wifi calling. I use mobile data and then link to Hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

I cant find a link (reference) but reading between the lines, it has to be `Wifi Calling`.

- For this to work, it has to use Wifi provided externally and you cant simultaneously use Wifi and provide a Wifi Hotspot.
- It is also possible that they want to remove any reason for voice quality to suffer.

So turn it off.  It is under `Settings` > `Connections`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: However, I never have Wifi switched on. I always use my mobile data on the phone and then link my computer to the Hotspot. Agreed, Wifi and Hotspot can't be used together. So, thanks for the suggestion but that's not the problem!

Comment: Hi Rohit, I think I may have pinned down the problem. The S23+ can take 2 SIM cards. If using data on SIM1 (private) and using my Hotspot, and then a call comes in on SIM2 (work), that will kill the Hotspot as it can't handle using both SIMs simultaneously? .., or vice-versa? I'm testing it now having switched to using data on SIM2 so hopefully work calls won't now kill the Hotspot? Does that make sense to you? Thanks for your thoughts :-)